# Program To Cascade/Tile Windows

Tags: lubuntu, window-manager, tiling

I have perhaps ten or fifteen windows open.

I'd like a program which automatically resizes all the windows and arranges them in columns and rows across the screen (a grid formation), automatically figuring out the largest size for the windows so that they still fit.

This isn't an "Expose" type program - I want the windows to stay resized.

I am using OpenBox to do my window management and am otherwise happy with it, I don't want to find a whole new window manager just to solve this problem.

The program [Tile](http://ftp.unixdev.net/pub/debian-udev/pool/main/t/tile/) is almost perfect, but it doesn't know how to lay the windows out in a grid formation.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you should try a [tiling window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager), like [Xmonad](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xmonad/), [dwm](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dwm/), or [Awesome](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/awesome/). I am using Xmonad and very happy with it, although I seldom use more than 3–4 windows on a workspace. But if you have a monitor big enough, I think, it can be configured.

Comment: As per my question, I would really like an independent program that does this, or something built into my existing window manager (OpenBox), with which I am otherwise satisfied.

Comment: Yes, i missed that part, sorry. But I'll mention that I switched to Xmonad from Openbox and had no need to switch back since then.

Answer (score 2):

I run lubuntu 12.04 w/ OpenBox and installed x-tile (via Synaptic Package Manager) to provide the functionality you describe.  Has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

to cascade windows on ubuntu unity window manager, you can use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

xy=20;
for windowId in `xdotool search xterm`; do 
    xdotool windowmove --sync $windowId $xy $xy; 
    ((xy+=40)); 
done
```

I needed for the loads of xterms I am using, works great!

For all windows, it requires some adjustments...